# aws golang sdk make asynchronous create instance calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

I want to make asynchronous calls to AWS service for creating a volume, using aws cloud sdk golang. The response returns a request id. Is it possible to make a query on this request id to get the status of operation?
I am using aws go sdk.

If this is not possible, does aws provide REST APIs. 
code looks like
result, err := ec2client.CreateVolume(input)

output contains same attributes as below output
CreateVolumeResponse->
59dbff89-35bd-4eac-99ed-be587EXAMPLE

result contains requestId

Comment: Has anyone used this request id to get more information. Please suggest.

Comment: Is this question open to public?